# Can I upgrade a specific lot?

Tags: bit-city

As I purchase more lots and expand my city, the lots get more expensive. I am able to save up money to purchase additional lots by upgrading those I already own (and other services).  Is there a way to upgrade my newest lots first instead of cycling through upgrading all of my other lots? I would like to have my newest lots catch up in levels and the wait time is significantly shorter for the newer lots as new lots start at level two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no current way to Upgrade a specific Lot without the Bux.